# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-migrate

I am new to sqlalchemy and trying to create tables in mysql.Created a virtual environment and executed below commands.
pip3 install sqlalchemy
pip3 install sqlalchemy-migrate

Python version- 3.6.4
but when I try to execute the command "python models.py" on terminal it pops an error

```
File "models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, MetaData, ForeignKey, DateTime, Float, BigInteger, String, func
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'
```

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, MetaData, ForeignKey, DateTime, Float, BigInteger, String, func

import helper.connection_util as connection_util

metadata = MetaData()

# employee TABLE
employee = Table('employee', metadata,
                    Column('employee_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
                    Column('employee_name', String(100)),
                    Column('employee_designation', String(100)),

metadata.create_all(connection_util.get_connection())
```

Comment: did u add `import sqlalchemy'` ?

Comment: Did you activate said virtual env? And are you sure `pip3` is the command from your venv, and not for example `pip`?

Comment: Yea i have added import sqlalchemy' @prateek , also activated my virtual env and its pip3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like sqlalchemy did not install. You can try using `sudo pip3 install sqlalchemy`.

You can confirm the install by running python in interactive mode and using the following commands:

```
$ python3
>>> import sqlalchemy
>>> sqlalchemy.__version__
```

This should give you the version of sqlalchemy you have.

Comment: had to uninstall sqlalchemy and install again for it to be working. Issue resolved now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: for my case, i just run pip install sqlalchemy, and it worked